# I want to create an array of words from a txt document in C#.

Tags: c#

The Split method returns an error.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] ebook = File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\Documents\\x.txt").ToArray();

        string[] words = ebook.Split(' ');

    }
```

Comment: And what is that error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `File.ReadAllText`:

```
var ebook = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\Documents\\x.txt");
var words = ebook.Split(' ');
```

You were using `File.ReadLines` that returns an `IEnumerable<string>` representing each line of your `.txt`, but if you want to split all words it is more "comfortable" to split from a single string, and `File.ReadAllText` returns a string with all the text in your file.

[File.ReadAllText documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not `File.ReadLines(...).Split(' ')` but `ReadAllText(...).Split()`

```
string[] words = File.ReadAllText(path).Split();
```

You can use the `Split()` to split by every [white-space](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) including new-line characters or tabs.